# Crear elementos del DOM con jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

Necesito crear elementos de una manera que no sea muy confusa y fácil de darle mantenimiento para hacer un cambio.

Actualmente lo hago con este código con `.append()` y `.html()`:

```
$('.Selector').append(
  '<div class="dropdown">'+
    '<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">'+
      '<li><a href="#">Elemento Menu 1</a></li>'
    '</ul>'+
  '</div>'
)
```

Pero es demasiado confuso y difícil de darle mantenimiento, o hacer cambios de etiquetas.

**¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo mas fácil?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Investigando después de un rato encontré esta manera simple, para crear un elemento solo basta con poner la etiqueta  y separar con una coma los atributos:

```
$('<a/>', {
  'html' : 'Un <strong>nuevo</strong> enlace',
  'class' : 'new',
  'href' : 'foo.html'
});
```

Ejemplo de código similar a lo que queria lograr:

```js
$("<div>", {
    'class': 'dropdown'
}).append(
    $('<ul>', {
        'class': 'dropdown-menu',
        'aria-labelledby': 'dropdownMenu1'
    }).append(
      $('<li>')
        .append(
          $('<a>',{
            'href':'#',
            'text':'Hola Mundo'
          })
        )
    )
).hide().appendTo('#otraDiv').fadeIn('slow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='otraDiv'></div>
```

<kbd>[Referencia](https://www.funcion13.com/anade-nuevos-elementos-complejos-al-dom-de-forma-elegante/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

esta es una solucion que hice hace poco, si! lo sé es un poco tediosa pero con Brackets y emmet se facilita todo...

```
        var icon = "./assets/icons/headset.png";

    var cadena = '';            

cadena += "          <div class='cd-timeline-block'>";
cadena += "                <div class='cd-timeline-img'>";
cadena += "                    <img src='"+icon+"' alt='user-picture'>";
cadena += "                </div>";
cadena += "                <div class='cd-timeline-content'>";
cadena += "                    <h4 class='text-center text-titles'>1 - YecidMoreno (Escritor)</h4>";
cadena += "                 <p class='text-center'>";
cadena += "                        <i class='zmdi zmdi-star zmdi-hc-fw'></i>";
cadena += "                        <i class='zmdi zmdi-star zmdi-hc-fw'></i>";
cadena += "                        <i class='zmdi zmdi-star zmdi-hc-fw'></i>";
cadena += "                        <i class='zmdi zmdi-star zmdi-hc-fw'></i>";
cadena += "                        <i class='zmdi zmdi-star-half zmdi-hc-fw'></i>";
cadena += "                         <a href='perfil.html' class='link-perfil'>Visitar Perfil</a>";
cadena += "                    </p>";
cadena += "                    <span class='cd-date'><i class='zmdi zmdi-calendar-note zmdi-hc-fw'></i> 07/07/2017</span>";
cadena += "                </div>";
cadena += "            </div>  ";



                div1 = $(cadena);
                $("#cd-timeline").prepend(div1);
```