# Agregar elementos en el DOM

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hola necesito añadir un atributo clase diferente para cada etiqueta a dentro de un li pero no se como hacerlo. Me podéis ayudar sería con jquery

Comment: Pon el código que tienes para ver como lo hacemos.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Crear elementos del DOM con jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40754/crear-elementos-del-dom-con-jquery)

Comment: @PabloLozano No es exactamente un duplicado ya que aunque en el título habla de agregar elementos lo que el OP pide en realidad es agregar un atributo a un elemento

Answer (score 0):

trás el append que genera los li

```
li.setAttribute("class", "nombredelaclase");
```

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta porque pondría la misma clase en el `li`, pero en la pregunta se menciona que busca poner una clase diferente en los elementos de dentro del `li`. No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera utilizando `jQuery`. Toma en cuenta que tu array de classes debe ser del mismo tamaño que tu número de elementos `li`:

```js
var classes = ['classone', 'classtwo', 'classthree'];
var i = 0;        
$('#milista').find('li').each(function(){
    let $element = $(this);
    $element.attr('class',classes[i]);
    i++;
});
```

```css
.classone{
 color: red;
}
.classtwo{
 color: blue;
}
.classthree{
 color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = "milista">
    <li>Uno</li>
    <li>Dos</li>
    <li>Tres</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta porque, aunque pondría diferentes clases, sería directamente en el `li`, pero en la pregunta se menciona que busca poner una clase diferente en los elementos de dentro del `li`. No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es añadir una clase, pero la misma a todos los "a" dentro de "li" no hace falta hacer un bucle, puedes hacer simplemente

```
$("li a").addClass("laclase");
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si algunos `li` tienen un `a`, otros un `div` y otros un `span`? ¿Y se debería incluir la clase sólo en los elementos que sea hijos directos o también en nietos y demás? No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real. Lee [answer] para más información.